# Notification from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm building an alarm clock which will show notification after desired time . For this I have used alarmmanager and broadcastreceiver to display notification.
I have used notification builder to build the notification .My problem is that broadcastreceiver is not displaying notification at given time .

MainActivty.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = et.getText().toString();
                int time = Integer.parseInt(s);
                setAlarm(time);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setAlarm(int time){
        i++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
       this.getApplicationContext(), i, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
       + (time * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + time + " seconds",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /**Toast.makeText(context, "Time is up!!!!.",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
      .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        **/
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                // Set Icon
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall)
                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker("ticker")
                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle("new Notification")
                // Set Text
                .setContentText("new message")
                // Add an Action Button below Notification
                //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Action Button", pIntent)
                // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                //.setContentIntent(pIntent)
                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true);



        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

     }
}
```

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alarm.MainActivity" >


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope question is clear :)

Comment: Is the method onReceive of your broadcast being called?

Comment: @hmartinezd yes it is being called commented code above notificationcompatbuilder is working .

Comment: Can you provide us with your error stack trace to have a better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, I think the problem is, that you are required to set up the small icon. Without it, notification won't show at all.

Comment: thanks it worked . But another problem is that notification doesn't show when app is not open .

Comment: You need to register channel first. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280773/3394380) .